# How to make a single list from lists when lists are results of a function?

Tags: python, json, list, parsing

I have json file like:

```
{
    "level0name":{
      "level1name":[
        {
            "notkey":null,
            "key":"Some text 626 dollars."
        },
        {
            "notkey":null,
            "key":"Some text 3213 dollars."
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

and python code that parse json with regex

```
import json
import re
path = 'name.json'
def parser():
    with open(path, 'r') as jfile:
        data = json.loads(jfile.read())
        for i in data["level0name"]["level1name"]:
            try:
                all_messages = (i['key'])
                a = re.findall(u'[0-9]{1,}\sdollars.', all_messages)
                for i in a:
                    print(i)
            except KeyError:
                continue   
parser()
```

Result of function gives me many lists like, and can't merge it.

```
[625 dollars]
[3213 dollars]
[121 dollars]
[692 dollars]
```

How can i get single list? Maybe I doing something wrong while parsing? 
Just need a single comma-separated list. Like:

```
[625, 3213, 121, 692]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly change your regex so you include a positive lookahead along with a list:

```
import json
import re
path = 'name.json'
def parser():
   with open(path, 'r') as jfile:
      data = json.loads(jfile.read())
      final_list = [] #for collecting the data
      for i in data["level0name"]["level1name"]:
         try:
             all_messages = (i['key'])
             a = re.findall(u'[0-9]{1,}(?=\sdollars\.)', all_messages)
             if a:
                final_list.append(int(a[0])) #append to final_list
         except KeyError:
            continue   
parser()
```

Or, you can read the file and apply regex:

```
import re
final_data = map(int, re.findall('\d+(?=\sdollars\.)', open('path.json').read()))
```

Comment: thanks, first one return many lists too, but like: [625][625, 3213][625, 3213, 121][625, 3213, 121, 692]. Second solutions is really good! thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Using a slightly longer JSON input file:

```json
{
    "level0name":{
      "level1name":[
        {
            "notkey":null,
            "key":"Some text 626 dollars."
        },
        {
            "notkey":null,
            "key":"Some text 3213 dollars."
        },
        {
            "notkey":null,
            "key":"Some text 121 dollars."
        },
        {
            "notkey":null,
            "key":"Some text 692 dollars."
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Along with this code:

```
import json
import re

path = 'name.json'

def parser():
    results = []
    with open(path, 'r') as jfile:
        data = json.loads(jfile.read())
        for i in data["level0name"]["level1name"]:
            try:
                match = re.search(r'([0-9]{1,})\sdollars.', i['key'])
                if match:
                    results.append(match.group(1))
            except KeyError:
                continue

    return results

print(parser())  # -> ['626', '3213', '121', '692']
```

Seems to do what you want. Note how a pair of parentheses were added to the regex pattern to indicate the portion (aka group) of the pattern has characters of interest. These are *capturing* parentheses as opposed to non-capturing parentheses, `(>:...)`, in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)—in other words regular parentheses are the kind that do capturing.